# is there is a command in bash that checks if a program can or cannot run

Tags: bash

I am just beginning to learn how to make bash scripts.

I want to know if there is a way to test if a program can run or not. For example, I want to test if NCL runs.

If I write `NCL` on a terminal I get

```
xxx$ ncl
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgomp.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/ncl-6.2.1/bin/ncl
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

That means that `NCL` is already installed, but the program cannot run due to a lack of a library.

I want to know if there is a command in bash that gives me 1 or 0 depending if `NCL` (or some other program) runs or doesn't run.

Comment: In this case, the `ncl` command ran, but it failed. The fact that it failed due to a missing library as opposed to some other error probably isn't something that bash can reliably detect.

Comment: if you specifically talking missing dependencies take a look at ldd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to check the return value of the command in bash like this...

```
somecommand  argument1 argument2
RETVAL=$?
[ $RETVAL -eq 0 ] && echo Success
[ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] && echo Failure
```

Comment: @AJaramillo Succinctly, `somecommand  argument1 argument2 && echo Success || echo Failure` or, as it can be more useful in a shell script, `somecommand  argument1 argument2 || return` to stop processing if a command cannot be run or stops in error.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the return code of the ncl command. Try ncl and after your get the error message type echo $? and see the output. This value gives you the return code of the previously typed command which is ncl in our case. If the value is not 0 then ncl cannot run.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Matt and Subashini, your answers helped me a lot.
The problem was very easy to solve.
Following your advice I created a ncl script file called 'ncltest.ncl' that open and close ncl just to check. Then the bash script that checks is this:

```
ncl ncltest.ncl
testfile=$?
if [ $testfile -eq 0 ]; then
 echo 'It worked'
else
 echo 'It did not work'
fi
```

In the case of `NCL` it returns 0 if worked and other number depending of the problem.